# POST method was removed after .htaccess apache rewirte

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having problems with posting POST data after adding .htaccess, here is my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ index.php$1 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1&args[1]=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_\@\.]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1&args[1]=$2&args[2]=$3 [L]
```

please help me, where i am doing wrong? POST method is not working after the htaccess rules.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just terminated my test, here my explanation, and rulesset you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.php [QSA,L,NC] 

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1&args[1]=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_\@\.]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1&args[1]=$2&args[2]=$3 [L]
```

As you have neither Redirect, nor [R] flag, POSTed data are not lost, only Redirect thows all posted data.

A php script as action of POST can accept both $_POST and $_GET, here your **$args** remains in $_GET array in PHP. Other posted data are in $_POST.

So please test this in index.php:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>
\$_GET
";
var_dump($_GET);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>
\$_POST
";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<form action="souper/ppan/ppm/" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="super" value="man" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

You'll see not only $_POST data, but also $_GET variables shown by index.php.

I've gotten this on Google Chrome:

```
$_GET
array(1) {
  ["args"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "souper"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "ppan"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "ppm"
  }
}
$_POST
array(2) {
  ["super"]=>
  string(3) "man"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(7) "Valider"
}
```

Comment: Hi there, it is working on root folder, but it is not working on sub folders, root folder has different htaccess which i can not see it, i am testing the website on university server, so, i do not have root folders htaccess.

Comment: I tested it in the sub directory /stack/.htaccess, it works. your root /.htaccess may have some influence on the rewrite. You can try to isolate, using only /subdir/.htaccess to test if it works.

Comment: by adding [QSA,L,NC]  and removing RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST helped, it is working now, i do not know but it is working, thank you for you tip!

Comment: How do i isolate it? i will need it for feature problems?

Comment: I left the University more than 20 years ago... how are you? ISOLATE: rename /.htaccess to /old.haccess, or comment all lines in it, just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

**`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next next `RewriteRule`.**

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
## don't do anything for POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ index.php$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1&args[1]=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_\@\.]+)[\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\/]$ index.php?args[0]=$1&args[1]=$2&args[2]=$3 [L]
```